# wix/react-native-navigation: Drawer does not swipe on Fill View

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

Drawer does not swipe if View with style absoluteFillObject

```
styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
  }
}
```